# multi-criteria decision making methods in R

Tags: r, analysis, fuzzy

I know R a little bit. I want to use multi-criteria decision making methods in R. I wanted to start with Fuzzy ahp and Fuzzy TOPSIS. I found the R package but could not find an example for fuzyy TOPSIS I could not understand the sample in the package very well. Can somebody help me how to do it?

Comment: The question is too broad. You need to come up with a concrete example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to choose a car based on price, color, engine power. So I have 3 criteria and 4 alternatives. I want to use fuzzy topsis and fuzyy ahp while doing this. But I could not find an illustrative example of fuzzy topsis. So I haven't tried anything. As I understood Fuzzy ahp a little more, but I would still like to examine more examples.
I looked at the examples at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FuzzyMCDM/FuzzyMCDM.pdf but I could not understand. Thank you for your attention.